# Change default wallpapers directory in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, directory, default

I'm trying to build a custom distro and I can't find the xml file in ubuntu 16.04 which lets you change the default wallpapers and the directory. It would be really very helpful if someone can help give a detailed procedure of how to do it. Thank you.